# Can't add a layout to Ember.Select

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to create a custom CSS dropdown which requires me to add a wrapper class to my Select view. I've attempted to add the code by reopening Ember.Select, but the behavior is not working as intended.

In my JS, I have this defined:

```
Ember.Select.reopen({
  layout: Ember.Handlebars.compile("<div class='select-layout'>{{yield}}</div>") 
});
```

In my template, I have:

```
{{view "select" content=model}}
```

However, my resulting HTML is:

```
<select id="ember257" class="ember-view ember-select">
  <option id="ember270" class="ember-view" value="red">red</option>
  <option id="ember273" class="ember-view" value="yellow">yellow</option>
  <option id="ember276" class="ember-view" value="blue">blue</option>  
</select>
```

I set up a JSFiddle for this which can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rbn6qa9x/

If there's a trick to this, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are out, components are in:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ciwifajaze/1/

Just define your template, no yield necessary in this case:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/custom-select">
    <div class='select-layout'>{{view "select" content=content}}</div>
</script>
```

Since you are not doing anything that requires JS, you can just use the component object that ember will automatically create for you behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks for your answer. this could work, but rather than creating an entirely new component, i'd like to find out how to add a layout to a built-in view. seems simple enough, right? i also have been behind in the ember 2.0 scene, so perhaps you have a point that im missing :)

Comment: Couple things going on here. See the Select view has a "tagName" of "select" meaning that ember renders that as the containing tag, <select> is not even in the handlebars. So you could reopen the tagName to div but then you lose all the other attribute bindings that are assumed to be on the tag level. I assure you the component example i gave you would be the most "ember way". For purely academic purposes, if you needed the view to do it, you could do http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ciwifajaze/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the additional div, you could use the classNames property:

```
    classNames: ['select-layout']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only adds the class to the Select element. I need it to be wrapped by something.